# Possible AttributeError bug in to_sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm not sure if this behaviour in [to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) (pandas 0.13.1) is intended to be. When I create a dataframe whithout columns names and try to write in an sql db

```
dfi = DataFrame(randn(3, 10))
dfi.to_sql(name = to_table, con=connection, flavor='mysql', if_exists='replace')
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in get_schema(frame, name, flavor, keys)
        308     lookup_type = lambda dtype: get_sqltype(dtype.type, flavor)
        309     # Replace spaces in DataFrame column names with _.
    --> 310     safe_columns = [s.replace(' ', '_').strip() for s in frame.dtypes.index]
        311     column_types = lzip(safe_columns, map(lookup_type, frame.dtypes))
        312     if flavor == 'sqlite':

    AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

If I set column headers with 
`dfi.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']`,

the writing into the db goes smooth. The real dataframe I'm trying to push into a database is a MultiIndex dataframe and obviously some columns are not labelled.

```
                   id month values                                                            
stats                       count        mean         std  min     25%    50%     75%     max
0                  1   Jan   2108  233.373102  107.521779   33  160.00  209.0  275.00   744.0
1                  1   Feb   1920  255.720573  111.454035   45  175.00  230.0  318.25   750.0
2                  1   Mar   2108  295.674810  113.522911   59  219.00  277.0  346.00   803.0
3                  1   Apr   2017  287.206247   99.577189  112  216.00  267.0  342.00   876.0
4                  1   May   2077  224.939336   80.810044   93  168.00  207.0  259.00   627.0
```

Comment: I also found [this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4227) but I have no clue how this issue get solved.

Comment: mi columns (and index in 0.13.1) are not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because integer column names are not supported in the sql version in pandas 0.13.1 (and below). You could easily get around this with (if you don't want to give other names) this before writing it to sql:

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
```

Starting from pandas 0.14, the sql functions are based on sqlalchemy, and integer column names and mult-index index are supported now.
Multi-index columns are not yet supported, but it is also not clear what should be the output in sql I think? So it will be up to the user to first drop a level or flatten the multi-index.